# Adding multiple objects in Xcode Core Data one to many

Tags: xcode, core-data, one-to-many

I have two elements in Core Data:

- News (with items like topic, message, date)
- Pictures (with one item: link to the image URL)

Every news item can have multiple pictures (i.e. one to many relationship).

In Xcode the elements are set up correctly.

Using XML I import news data. On every news item i have two arrays:

- `newsArray`
- `ImageArray`

The `newsArray` is loaded with all information for the News element. The `imageArray` is loaded with URLS of images that belongs to that news element.

I have sorted out how to put the information of the newsArray into Core Data but my problem is as follows:

How do I input and save the objects of the `imageArray` into the Core Data Pictures element with the relation to the news item I just added?

I have some code that I use now for saving the news element but it is a little bit overloaded with XML loading stuff, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through your `imageArray` and add the images to the news item as a relationship one by one. When generating the `NSManagedObject` subclasses Xcode should have created these setter and accessor methods automatically for you:

```
for (NSDictionary *d in imageArray) {
  Image *i = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Image"
      inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
  i.url = d[@"imageURL"];
  [newsItem addImagesObject:i];  // Xcode generated method
}
// save
```

Comment: Ok, but what i don't understand:
I first upload a news item, for example with id 300. How does Core Data know that the images I upload after that belong to that news item with id 300?

Comment: You add them as a relationship, as demonstrated above. The foreign key scheme with ids is completely hidden by core data. If you need to update an item from *outside* Core Data you could use this id to identify it - but you would then still just use the relationship to store it in Core Data.